# Fastest way to implement completeness score of two 3D sparse binary numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, 3d, comparison

I'm currently running a segmentation model, previously in 2D, and now moving to 3D. As part of the performance measurement metrics, I need to compute the completeness score of the segmented image in regards to the ground-truth image; that is computing the fraction of the 1-valued pixels from the ground-truth that are covered by the 1-valued pixels of the segmented image. The ground-truth is binary and very sparse, and so is the prediction. Here is a 2D simplified example of what it could look :

[image: 2D example]

In red is the ground-truth path and in green the predicted path, this image would have a completeness score of around 0.7 with slack=1 (see below). Until now I've been computing the completeness in the following way :

```
distances_pred = ndimage.distance_transform_edt((np.logical_not(pred_s)))

true_pos_area_pred = distances_pred<=slack
false_neg_area = distances_pred>slack

true_positives_pred = np.logical_and(true_pos_area_pred, gt_s).sum() # length of the matched reference
false_negatives = np.logical_and(false_neg_area, gt_s).sum()

completeness = true_positives_pred/(true_positives_pred + false_negatives)
```

(slack here is set to 1, and it's to have an additional tolerance of 1 pixel away for still considering the prediction and the ground-truth as overlapping).
In 2D and with small images it works perfectly fine, but as I was moving to 3D images and larger scales, and having to compute it every iteration for many iterations, I've come to the conclusion that this step is really slowing down my model in a undesired manner. I've now come up with implementations that have improved the time it takes, but it's still not efficient enough when I have to do long runs.

Question : what would be the fastest way to compute that completeness ratio (between 0.0 and 1.0), considering that I do not need the positions of the overlapping pixels, only the ratio ?

Methods that I've tried (pseudocode here) :

```
# 1)
gt_ones = np.argwhere(gt == 1)
L = len(gt_ones)
pred_ones = np.argwhere(dilate(pred, slack=1) == 1)
overlap = sum((gt_ones[:, None] == pred_ones).all(-1).any(-1))
comp = overlap/L

# 2)
L = len(gt_ones)
comp = (L - np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(gt, dilate(pred, slack=1))))/L
```

Comment: IMO computing the full distance function is overkill. Instead, compute a dilation of one of the segmentations with a "ball" structuring element, then count the common voxels. (Taking a cube instead of a sphere, the dilation is separable and can be performed cheaply.)

Comment: Unless you have a compressed representation of the segmentations, any solution will take time proportional to the image size, which is large in 3D.